# Intranet keyword url redirection

Tags: url, redirect, intranet, url-shortener

I am looking for a way to provide configurable keyword-based URL redirection for users on an intranet (within a company), so that entering a URL of the form "go/ would redirect to an pre-defined URL associated with that keyword. For example, "go/accounting" might redirect to "http://company.com/accounting". The destination URL could be any valid URL either internal or external to the company. If there is no existing keyword defined, the browser should present a page where a new URL could be associated with that keyword. I used to work at a company that had something like this implemented, and it was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Host file should be a perfect solution for you.

When you are browsing the internet and writing a name in the url(e.g. facebook.com) the computer need to translte this name you wrote to an ip address.

Host file is a file that the system will use first when trying to translate name to ip, if you will add a line to the host file like this:
0.0.0.0 Www.facebook.com

Every time you will try to browse to facebook it will direct you to the ip 0.0.0.0.
So for your question you should add a line like this:
`<your company web ip>`

The host file is located in: `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc`